# How to set a blurry background image with sharp edges?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a blurry background image for a div container. But if I set the blur filter the edges also will get blurry causing the blurred image to overflow it's frame. This is what I tried till now:

```css
.one {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/JCyxUxA.jpg"); */
/*  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
   background-size: contain;
  */}

.a {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/JCyxUxA.jpg");
}

.b {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/O1jVhYH.jpg");
}

.thing {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bl {
  filter: blur(20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="one t">
  <img class="thing" src="https://i.imgur.com/JCyxUxA.jpg" alt="">
</div>  
<div class="one t">
  <img class="thing bl" src="https://i.imgur.com/JCyxUxA.jpg" alt="">
</div>  
<!-- <div class="one a">
</div>
<div class="one b">
</div>
 -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `overflow:hidden;` to its container (class `one` in your case).
This will hide every part of the children elements that is overflowing its container

Comment: Doesn't work. the image after blurring isn't overflowing the container on the sides.

Comment: You can solve that with another `div` around your `img`, with the width and height you need

Comment: as @Damiano said, `overflow` fix your problem. what do you expect?

Comment: @Damiano The problem is, I don't know before hand what the size of the wrapping div should be beforehand. The background image is just supposed to fill the container. It might be limited by the width or height depending on wether it's landscape or portrait.